io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: chat.example.ChatService/chat
I have reviewed other posts where the subject line's error is mentioned, but none of these have helped. I have the server in one project and the client in another.
This is my Chat.proto file for both, they're identical:
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
package chat.example;

message ChatMessage {
    string from = 1;
    string message = 2;
}

message ChatMessageFromServer {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    ChatMessage message = 2;
}

service ChatService {
    rpc chat(stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessageFromServer);
}

The server is being run on http://localhost:50051. The client appears to be connecting to the server but then I get the following error:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: chat.example.ChatService/chat
Disconnected
        at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:532)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:481)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:564)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:72)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:729)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:710)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)

But the method is defined in both projects, with same package, in the generated class ChatServiceGrpc.java:
public static final java.lang.String SERVICE_NAME = "chat.example.ChatService";

  // Static method descriptors that strictly reflect the proto.
  private static volatile io.grpc.MethodDescriptor<chat.example.Chat.ChatMessage,
      chat.example.Chat.ChatMessageFromServer> getChatMethod;

  @io.grpc.stub.annotations.RpcMethod(
      fullMethodName = SERVICE_NAME + '/' + "chat",

Anyone have an idea of where to point me?
Originally, the Chat.proto files had different names, resulting in different method names as well. Additionally, I had these under different packages but I have now made them the same.
When I run netstat -ano | findstr: 50051 , I get the following in the command prompt:
  TCP    0.0.0.0:50051          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       33960
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50051        127.0.0.1:57252        ESTABLISHED     33960
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57252        127.0.0.1:50051        ESTABLISHED     28372
  TCP    [::]:50051             [::]:0                 LISTENING       33960

This seems to demonstrate to me that a connection is being established between client and server. I am not, however, getting the service behaviour as defined by the .proto file and the Method not found error is occurring.

Where is your class actually implementing the server?  UNIMPLEMENTED usually indicates you haven't implemented the right function there.  You've shown us that you've defined the service API, but not that you've actually implemented it.
